# Appium inspector error Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 70

Tags: javascript, automation, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I am trying to connect my real device with apppium inspector. I am using following capabilities

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "appium:platformVersion": "16.7",  
  "appium:udid": "",
  "appium:noReset": true,
  "appium:deviceName": "Admin's iPhone",
  "appium:app": "/Users/admin/Downloads/app.ipa",
}
```

appium inspector shows error:

```
Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 70.
This usually indicates an issue with the local Xcode setup or WebDriverAgent project configuration
or the driver-to-platform version mismatch.
```

And on appium logs I can see this error:

```
Closing the connection
[DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[XCUITestDriver@adb6 (5da55870)] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[iProxy@63340fb9:8100] The connection has been closed
[AppiumDriver@38cd] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1706311999116 (04:33:19 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time))
[AppiumDriver@38cd] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 70. This usually indicates an issue with the local Xcode setup or WebDriverAgent project configuration or the driver-to-platform version mismatch. Consider setting 'showXcodeLog' capability to true in order to check the Appium server log for build-related error messages.. Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
[AppiumDriver@38cd]     at quitAndUninstall (/Users/admin/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:794:15)
[AppiumDriver@38cd]     at /Users/admin/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:880:13
[AppiumDriver@38cd]     at wrapped (/Users/admin/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:93:13)
[AppiumDriver@38cd]     at retry (/Users/admin/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:66:13)
[AppiumDriver@38cd]     at retryInterval (/Users/admin/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:103:10)
[AppiumDriver@38cd]     at /Users/admin/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:819:7
[HTTP] <-- POST /session 500 34035 ms - 1812
```

Comment: as I remember properly, it is not possible to use an .ipa file, you need to use an archive with the extension .app

Comment: @DimaBerezovskyi I am using .ipa and trying to connect appium inspector with real device. It install app but its not showing me on appium inspector therefore I am not able to locate elements.